# Size of "Bytes sent" in apache log file

Tags: apache, logging

I added to my apache log file another information-> %O which is indicated to bytes sent to user **including headers**. Here is my question how to count the size of **HEADERS** ? I have already tried $ENV{'CONTENT_LENGTH'} but it isn't it.

I believe there must be the way to determine HEADERS size from CGI script but as for now have no idea how.

Thanks for help in advance ;)

Answer (score 1):

%b logs the size of bytes **without** headers, so you can calculate the diff to get the header size.